# Как сделать анимацию SVG Path'ов через Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg

<strike>Нужно сделать 4 отдельных элемента (!важно, чтобы при наведении на каждый анимация была именно для него)</strike>. Сделать так, чтобы не зависело от размера экрана, чтобы виджет можно было делать любого размера и был родитель `div` (Корневой элемент, размер которого я установлю сам, а размеры, паддинги, маргины дочерних элементов установятся автоматически)

---

**UPD**

В ответе дали подсказку что можно управлять `svg path` как обычным `DOM` элементом. Как это можно сделать (*P.S. У меня в теге svg моего объекта нет некоторых тегов, вроде fill, да и вообще каждый `path` содержит набор цифр сохранил из Adobe Illustrator*)

[image: Пример того, что должно выйти]

Comment: Почему именно div? Гораздо проще сделать то же самое через svg.
Делается svg с 4 элементами + анимация по вашему вкусу через css+js svg элемент, в вашем случае каждый пазл, будет представлен тегом `<path>`. Это практически обычный dom–элемент и можете делать с ним что вам нужно. Единственные отличия в вашем случае это при использовании css для svg элементов используются другие атрибуты, к примеру, `background-color` анналог в svg fill.

Comment: Для каждой из 4 паззл отдельная аминация нужна по ховеру

Comment: Как уже писали ранее, ваш ответ ответа не содержит. Можно по конкретнее, как именно мне выделить все `path` из `svg`? Как ими манипулировать и т.п.

Comment: Вот [решение](https://jsfiddle.net/5z37ksj6/) задавая размер элементу div  с классом .parent-puzzle вы будете получать нужный вам размер элементов думаю отрись-ка конкретно пазлов у вас проблем вызвать не должна для данных целей существует куча свободного софта.

Comment: @fens это не работает для анимации вроде `animate({ top: -10+'px'}, 500);`

Comment: Не совсем понял то есть animate? Это функция из спецификации css.

Comment: `Illustrator` вставляет `fill` и тп в `css` в том-же `svg` файле. Для вашей задачи вам придется все эти цифры путей писать руками, продумывать логику анимации. Хотя не очень понятно из задачи какая анимация тут нужна.

Comment: Ну вообще хотелось бы от изменения `fill` до смещения вроде `animate ({top : '-10px'})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно давать `id` каждому пути, либо переиспользовать из общего svg. 
Анимация для путей возможна `css transform translate`:

```css
svg {
  fill: green
}
.puzz {
  transition: all .4s
}
.puzz:hover {
  fill: red;
  transform: translate(0, -5px) scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display:none">
  <defs>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 0 80 L 80 80 L 80 0 Z" id="puzz" />
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="puzzle">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200">
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#puzz" class="puzz" />
    <use x="90" y="0" xlink:href="#puzz" class="puzz" />
    <use x="0" y="90" xlink:href="#puzz" class="puzz" />
    <use x="90" y="90" xlink:href="#puzz" class="puzz" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Можете каждому `use` задать свой `id` и анимировать его персонально.

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший ответ. Только нужно еще изменение размера для каждого по ховеру, как это сделать?

Comment: Исправил в ответе. `scale` но тут сбивается центр, надо играться с `transform-origin` либо действительно раскидать все по отдельным дивам и уже им давать все трансформации. Тем более вам придется скорее всего так-же менять `z-index`

Comment: а через атрибут никак нельзя? Я просто всё это в `jquery` загоняю и css анимировать через него не получается.

Comment: `css` сам анимируется у меня в примере, вы в `jquery` можете менять стиль вроде `.css({'transform': 'scale(1.1)'})`; но еще раз советую вам раскидать по дивам

Comment: мне нужно `.animate({'transform': 'scale(1.1)'}, 400)` - не работает.

Comment: По дивам боюсь не будет наложения спрайтов друг на друга

Comment: Я уже по div'aм пробовал и мне пришлось маргины вручную устанавливать, морока в общем

Comment: Там все проще и хитрее, вообще я писал что вместо jquery animate можно ставить css анимацию и при смене аттрибутов будет анимация. Вы лучше создайте новый топик как улучшить положения и там будет виднее, думаю подскажем там.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, позже создам